# Callback on SaveChanges in EFCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, autofac, dbcontext

I'm trying to do something like in my `DbContext`:

```
public System.Action<IEnumerable<EntityEntry>> OnSave;

public override int SaveChanges() {
    if(OnSave != null)
         OnSave(ChangeTracker.Entries());

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then DI (AutoFac) the `DbContext` into another class which can hook into the 'OnSave' function.

I'm looking for a single source of truth when this happens.

I don't think this will work or be reliable when `DbContext` is injected into multiple places since I'm pretty sure we end up with multiple instances of `DbContext` for every place it's injected into.

Comment: No sure this is what you are looking for, but if you configure your `DbContext` in container to be `InstancePerLifetimeScope`, you would get the same instance for every injection, within the request.

Comment: You could create a class which inherits from DbContext, and override the SaveChanges() method to call your own custom events

Comment: If you're attaching new event handlers through DI over the course of your application execution you could well shoot yourself in the foot. You'd have to ensure you're not double-attaching, that all references are detached before you dispose the context or you end up with memory leaks... it could be kind of bad. I would recommend solving whatever the problem is in some other way. We don't know what you're trying to actually solve, though, so no guidance for alternatives can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want your `OnSave` method to be a singleton (the same method used in all instances of your `DbContext`).

One way to solve this is to move your `Action` to a new class:

```
public class MySaveEventHandler {
     public System.Action<IEnumerable<EntityEntry>> OnSave;
}
```

Then add it as a singleton in your Startup.cs to make it available for dependency injection:

```
services.AddSingleton<MySaveEventHandler>();
```

Then change you `DbContext` constructor to accept that via DI and use that in your `SaveChanges` method:

```
MySaveEventHandler _mySaveEventHandler;

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, MySaveEventHandler mySaveEventHandler) : base(options) {
    _mySaveEventHandler = mySaveEventHandler;
}

public override int SaveChanges() {
    if(_mySaveEventHandler.OnSave != null)
         _mySaveEventHandler.OnSave(ChangeTracker.Entries());

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

To set the `OnSave` method, you simply get your single `MySaveEventHandler` instance via DI and set it. Then every instance of your `DbContext` will use it.

Side note: You could use an event instead of a delegate. Really I don't think it'll make much of a functional difference, but there's some interesting reading about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/distinguish-delegates-events