# Net Core: DBContext Override to run functionality when DBSet is modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a method when: ProductType Dbset is modified in any way, 
(insert, update, delete, etc) Console writes Hello.

Eventually team wants to append other intricate functionality. I want this in compilation time through overriding, Not execution run time with tracking, etc.

```
public class CustomStoreContext : StoreContext
{
    public CustomContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product>
    {
        console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

}

Do we have to override all DBSet modification functionalities, or is there easier way? 
* Also need to account for Add Entity Graph .https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework5/add-entity-graph-using-dbcontext.aspx

Would not like  not be on SaveChanges, since only looking for few Entities. Condition on SaveChanges can affect mass performance.

[image]
We are using EF Net Core 2.2

Comment: Easier way would be to write "Hello" where you are saving new values in your code.

Comment: I mean write it where you call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` not in `SaveChanges`

Comment: Just use built-in logging or implement own query logging, where you can check for table name being modified and write your "hello". If you want to add some business logic there, then you probably doing something wrong and now end up "fighting" a framework.

Comment: hi @Fabio does entity framework offer event notification when entity changes, instead of me proactively seeing whats changed?

Comment: This is one of the cases when company guidelines preventing you from being productive ;) If you want execute some business logic when specific tables being updated - wrap updating logic within a class and use this class everywhere where you need update those tables. With such wrapper you will be able to add any kind of logic or logging around those specific tables without affecting performance

Comment: hi @Fabio we have people writing prexisting dbcontext queries or not using repository patterns, so trying to get to dbcontext level

Comment: Good luck with that :) I believe you not updating same table from multiple places but only one or two. So shouldnät be difficult to wrap those functions within class

Comment: hi @Fabio since cannot override dbset, posting this question, you gave me a few ideas, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254853/net-core-entity-framework-changetracker-stream-into-log-to-query-afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override SaveChanges() and check if any entities that you are interested in are affected: [Callback on SaveChanges in EFCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412585/callback-on-savechanges-in-efcore).

If you are looking for a solution to execute some code when entries are changed but before they are saved to the DB (when you call `Products.Add()` for example), they you can refactor your codebase to [Repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core). That gives you additional layer on top of context where you can do whatever you need.

Comment: @DerrikRodgers I very doubt on performance degradation. Will appreciate for any evidences; tests or benchmarks.

Comment: @DerrikRodgers please elaborate on the requirements, I don't quite follow what you mean under 'compile time' - you'll have code executed in run time in any case ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ . Also please explain if there is anything else that does not meet question requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check a nuget package EntityFramework.Triggers

Link : https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers

We could do something like below:

```
  var storeContext  = new CustomerStoreContext() { TriggersEnabled = true };

    Triggers<Product>.Inserting += entry =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    };
```