# Reactive Extension Simple Example not Working with Number Generator

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-core, system.reactive

Trying to setup Reactive Extension for a simple example. Eg: there is random  Number Generator, and anytime Number Divisible by three is spotted, "Write Hello" and Observe the Event. However it does not seem to be working. Feel free to edit line, or rewrite code to make work correctly. Its a quick two page copy into  Console Program.

Eventually, want number generator to work in a stream , while SeeNumber observes in a Console program for one minute.

Code follows this resource: [Reactive Extensions](https://rehansaeed.com/reactive-extensions-part1-replacing-events/)

Goals which can be incorporated in code:

1. Make the Number Generator streaming
2. Also reading, are Subjects are good in RX? Feel free to modify code without subjects if true,

**Main.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var generateNumber = new GenerateNumber();
    var seeNumber = new SeeNumber(generateNumber);
    generateNumber.DivideByThreeSpotted.Subscribe(seeNumber.OnDivideByThreeSpotted);

    Console.WriteLine(generateNumber.NumberValue);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Produce Number:**

```
public class GenerateNumber
{
    public int NumberValue { get; set; }

    public GenerateNumber()
    {
        NumberValue = CreateData();
    }

    public Subject<GenerateNumber> divideByThreeSpotted = new Subject<GenerateNumber>();

    public IObservable<GenerateNumber> DivideByThreeSpotted
    {
        get { return this.divideByThreeSpotted; }
    }

    public int CreateData()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(0, 100);
    }

    public void SpotDivideByThree(GenerateNumber generateNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            if (NumberValue % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number Can be Divided by 3");
                this.divideByThreeSpotted.OnNext(generateNumber);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.divideByThreeSpotted.OnError(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

**See Number:**

```
public class SeeNumber : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable divideByThreeSpottedSubscription;

    public SeeNumber(GenerateNumber generateNumber)
    {
        this.divideByThreeSpottedSubscription = generateNumber.DivideByThreeSpotted.Subscribe(this.OnDivideByThreeSpotted);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.divideByThreeSpottedSubscription.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnDivideByThreeSpotted(GenerateNumber generateNumber)
    {
        GenerateNumber spottedDivisibleByThree = generateNumber;
    }
}
```

Creating a simple example from tutorial,

Comment: You don't ever call `SpotDivideByThree`, so yes, it won't reach it.

Comment: hi @PeterBons what would be new syntax line? I copy the tutorial, and thought I called it here,  generateNumber.DivideByThreeSpotted.Subscribe(seeNumber.OnDivideByThreeSpotted);