# ASP.NET Core- The DbContext of type 'ApplicationDbContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a public constructor accepting a single parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing Entity Framework Code-First in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API. I am using IdentityDbContext, and I have this code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUser;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
      : base(options)
    {

    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, ICurrentUserService currentUser, IDateTime dateTime) : base(options)
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new TransactionConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserRoleConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationRoleConfigurations());
    }
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach (var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (item.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUser.UserName;
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Added:
                    item.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUser.UserName;
                    item.Entity.CreatedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    item.Entity.DeletedBy = _currentUser.UserName;
                    item.Entity.DeletedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    item.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

When I want to create Migration using Add-Migration **InitialCreate -OutputDir Persistence\Migrations**

I got this error:

> The DbContext of type 'ApplicationDbContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions or has more than one constructor.

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding another constructor with one parameter only (DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)?

Comment: @Osama - I just added that, but still got the same error. See my updated code

Comment: You can only have that single constructor with the options parameter.

Comment: @DavidG - When I removed it, the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by wanting to inject services into the DbContext, which isn't that terrific of an idea.

Wrap it around: create a handler to handle the [DbContext.SavingChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savingchanges?view=efcore-6.0) event and update your entities in there.

See [Callback on SaveChanges in EFCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412585/callback-on-savechanges-in-efcore) for an implementation thereof.

Also, assuming `Transactions` inherits `AuditableEntity`, I'm not sure `ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>()` will do what you expect it to.

Comment: Why is injecting services a bad idea? The EF team do this all the time.

Comment: There's a difference between infrastructure/providers and application code. How are you going to unit test code that takes an ApplicationDbContext which calls GetService()? Loose coupling, high cohesion.

Comment: @CodeCaster - The error now becomes   Cannot resolve scoped service 'Persistence.Services.ICurrentUserService' from root provider.

Comment: @Ayobamilaye if you changed your code, please edit your question to show your new code, your DI setup and so on.

Comment: I still take issue with your comment that injecting services in the constructor is a bad idea, but I'm now with you on using `GetService`. I also don't think that you can use a scoped service with context pooling since all the contexts are shared across requests.

Comment: @DavidG I get that, it's a gut feeling that I can't properly describe. It's just that a DbContext should do one thing and one thing only: provide access to your database, through `DbSet<T>` properties and the `Set<T>()` method. Everything else should be extended from/attached to/subscribed to, not injected into the DbContext. Single responsibility.